# jquery simple overlay flickering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying a simple overlay on the page when the user hovers on the button but the issue is that it keeps flickering. I thought it was a timing issue so I tried giving it different fadein and fadeout timings but that didn't help either.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hover(function() {
    console.log('test');
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  opacity: .8;
}

.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">Testing</button>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bgpk2paL/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that your overlay is a sibling of your container, so when you mouseover the container, the overlay fades in, and once faded in the container doesn't see the mouse anymore and begins the fadeout part of the hover. If you moved the overlay *within* the container, then when you mouseover the container, the mouse will still register when the container fades in, and you won't get stuck in that flicker loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hover(function() {
    console.log('test');
    $(".overlay").stop().fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $(".overlay").stop().fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  opacity: .8;
}

.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">Testing</button>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a better way to do this? I can't have the overlay as a child element. I need it to be a sibling

Comment: You could try adding `pointer-events:none;` to your overlay CSS rules